Golang squirrel query builder build query which does not execute?
I have a code which does unit testing, where I prepare a database for the tests (I do not use sql-go-mock), so I want to insert returning id with a simple sql INSERT INTO, but for some reason pgx errors with panic: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" (SQLSTATE 42601), but the query does execute in a goland console.
What is wrong here? By the way, the code does not even work without RETURNING id.
Query built by the builder: INSERT INTO collections (name) VALUES (?),(?) RETURNING id
Simplified example below
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/merge?sslmode=disable"
    ctx := context.Background()
    pool, err := pgxpool.New(ctx, dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    type a struct {
        ID   uint
        Name string
    }

    as := []a{{
        Name: "asd",
    }, {
        Name: "zxc",
    }}

    stmt := sq.Insert("collections").Columns("name").
        Values(as[0].Name).Values(as[1].Name).
        Suffix("RETURNING id")

    query, args, err := stmt.ToSql()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = pool.QueryRow(ctx, query, args).Scan(&as)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", as)
}



The ? is not a valid parameter placeholder in PostgreSQL, instead PostgreSQL uses $N where N is the position of the argument, e.g. $1 for the first argument, $2 for the second, etc.

What you're probably missing is psql := sq.StatementBuilder.PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar), and then you should be able use the returned psql builder to build your queries with the correct placeholder format.
Alternatively you can also just append the .PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar) method call to your sq.Insert("collections")... statement.

psql := sq.StatementBuilder.PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

// You use question marks for placeholders...
sql, _, _ := psql.Select("*").From("elephants").Where("name IN (?,?)", "Dumbo", "Verna").ToSql()

/// ...squirrel replaces them using PlaceholderFormat.
sql == "SELECT * FROM elephants WHERE name IN ($1,$2)"


/// You can retrieve id ...
query := sq.Insert("nodes").
    Columns("uuid", "type", "data").
    Values(node.Uuid, node.Type, node.Data).
    Suffix("RETURNING \"id\"").
    RunWith(m.db).
    PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

query.QueryRow().Scan(&node.id)

Example taken from squirrel's README.

Here is the code, changed according to the @mkopriva's answer
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/merge?sslmode=disable"
    ctx := context.Background()
    pool, err := pgxpool.New(ctx, dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer pool.Close()

    var ids []int

    type a struct {
        ID   uint
        Name string
    }

    as := []a{{
        Name: "asd",
    }, {
        Name: "zxc",
    }}

    stmt := sq.Insert("collections").Columns("name").
        Values(as[0].Name).Values(as[1].Name).
        Suffix("RETURNING id").PlaceholderFormat(sq.Dollar)

    query, args, err := stmt.ToSql()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", args)

    rows, err := pool.Query(ctx, query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        if err := rows.Scan(&id); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        ids = append(ids, id)
    }

    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ids)
}

